# Deleting Bitbucket project avatar

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Is there a way to delete/remove the project avatar that has been uploaded.  I want to **REMOVE** entirely, **NOT** trying to change to another avatar.  The reason I want to remove is because I want my Jenkins Bitbucket plugin to generate random icons for each respective project.

Bitbucket server version **`5.14.4`**

There is a Jira issue regarding this but I couldn't see any **`Delete Avatar`** link/button.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-12276

[image]

[image]

Comment: IMHO (and most respectfully), UX has been a challenge with atlassian for a long time.